# Adding text to custom field in all posts of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm trying to add a piece of text at the start of my custom field "results_html" which is only on my custom post type "Results".  I want to add this text when any results post type is published.  I can't get the test text to show up in the field.  This is the code I have so far.

```
function gr_add_class_div_to_results(){
    $field_value = get_field('results_html');;
    if ($field_value){
        $field_value='test'.$field_value;
        update_field('results_html', $field_value);
    }
    else{

    }
}


add_action( 'publish_post', 'gr_add_class_div_to_results', 10, 2 );
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hello, at 1st sight seems like a typo on the if statement, where you have:     if (!field_value){ i believe you want to have     if ($field_value){
, check the $ before field_value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that - I was typing in a rush last night.  I tried it this morning with and without the if statement and the code still doesn't work so I'm unsure where I've went wrong.